# CListCtrl - get the length of the item text

Tags: winapi, mfc, clistctrl

I'm deriving from `CListCtrl`. Is there a way to find out how long the text contained in item `i` subitem `0` (first column) is? That info is required by `GetItemText()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 overloads for GetItemText(), you should use the one with 2 params. Like this:

```
CString txt = CListCtrl::GetItemText(item, column);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbtzx5b1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: CString to the rescue! Much appreciated.